# How can I export compositions with html-fontify?

Tags: display, htmlfontify, prettify-symbols-mode

Prettify-symbols-mode is a very nice way to make source code more readable, especially in math-heavy languages. Unfortunately, exporting to HTML with html-fontify-buffer doesn't respect prettifications.

It can be made to (I [wrote the code](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/.emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/htmlfontify/htmlfontify%2B.el) for that), but it breaks copy-pasting (the prettified symbols are copied, not their unprettified equivalents).

In other words, how can I export an Emacs lisp buffer to a webpage, while preserving prettifications and not breaking copy-paste?